# Tag suggestion broken for certain tags with hyphens

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I stumbled across something interesting when I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986080/non-templated-container-that-can-hold-anything) yesterday: Any tag that begins with `stl-` cannot be added. They appear in the drop down list, but when clicked or typed in full, revert to just `stl`.

e.g. `stl-container` reverts to `stl`.

Not sure if there are more that follow this trend, but I tested a few and they worked fine.

Comment: I also can't click the "info" link that appears when you hover over the suggested tag.  It acts like I clicked the suggestion's tag instead of the info link.  This wasn't happening when the feature was first introduced.

Comment: @Matthew I will agree that the info link doesn't seem to be working.  That was annoying when trying to look up synonym info.

Comment: [Related feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101554/make-the-synonym-of-tag-text-stand-out-or-otherwise-improve-this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is intended.

[stl-container](/questions/tagged/stl-container) is marked a synonym of [stl](/questions/tagged/stl) as shown on the [stl tag synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stl/synonyms).  Thus, choosing [stl-container](/questions/tagged/stl-container) will replace that tag with just [stl](/questions/tagged/stl).

I'm able to choose other stl- tags just fine (like [stl-algorithm](/questions/tagged/stl-algorithm)) on Windows 7/Chrome.  I think it was just a case of picking a tag synonym.

Comment: I thought that may have been the case after I posted and searched a bit, but it was not at all intuitive that that was happening, especially since I must have tried 2 different synonyms of `stl`. I did notice after reading this and trying again that it states it is a synonym at the very bottom in a small font, but not very noticeable in my opinion. Thanks for the insight, I'll *attempt* to take more notice in the future.

Comment: Wow, did **not** notice that. I'll make a feature request to make it clearer.

Comment: [Posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101554/make-the-synonym-of-tag-text-stand-out-or-otherwise-improve-this).