# Make the "synonym of tag" text stand out or otherwise improve this

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, design

When a tag synonym is suggested, it contains the text `(synonym of <tag>)` in tiny lettering -- identical to the tag description -- at the end of the description.

[image: screenshot]

This is *really* hard to notice without very careful reading and [causes confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/tag-suggestion-broken-for-certain-tags-with-hyphens).

I'd like to request that this text be made to stand out somehow, or possibly change the placement or something.  I liked the previous version where `(s)` came after the tag name -- perhaps you could put it after the number of questions, e.g:

> [stl-containers](/questions/tagged/stl-containers) **x 3042** (s)

This would be OK too:

> [stl-containers](/questions/tagged/stl-containers) **x 3042**
>           <sub>Synonym of [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl)</sub>
>   <sub>The Standard Template Library, or STL, is
>
>   not something I want to type about further.</sub>

**Edit:** The interface has been changed to the following:

[image: screenshot]

Looks pretty good to me!  I've removed the feature request, making this a discussion.

Comment: The `(s)` confused people too, but I agree having it as normal text at the end of the description is no better. This was actually on my to-do list to suggest a change for, heh.

Comment: Wow, yeah, is that actually there? The devs told me it had been implemented, but I haven't yet been able to see it. Guess I've never actually read all the way through the tag wiki excerpt to see if something is a synonym.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Awesome, similar to my recent edit but better.