# A new hyphenated tag can be created when an unhyphenated version exists as a synonym

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-creation

The tag [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) has two synonyns, [restful](/questions/tagged/restful) and [restful-web-services](/questions/tagged/restful-web-services).

Someone created [rest-ful](/questions/tagged/rest-ful) over on Stack Overflow [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16966939/168868).

Given that the system automatically redirects you to the "correct" tag when you try to use a hyphenated/unhyphenated alternative, shouldn't this also do the same thing when the hyphenated/unhyphenated alternative is a synonym?

Comment: No, because `rest-ful` *clearly* has so much more rest than `restful`. /sarcasm.

Comment: Pfft.  Give it a rest.

Comment: I sure am getting *tired* of these punny comments.

Comment: You're both ful of 'em

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag synonyms aren't computed automatically.  They are found via lookup.  Here's the [list of tag synonyms for Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=master&filter=all), and you can even suggest your own if you [at least 2500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).  The same path will work on all sites for tags specific to that site.  If you think `rest-ful` should redirect to `rest` (makes sense to me), then hop on over to the [SO synonym list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=master&filter=all) and make the suggestion.

For reference, this is the description of how synonyms work: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

**Update**:

The main problem here was that we just weren't checking the user-edited tag against the synonym list during tag validation.  When the form gets posted it gets through validation, and if the tag doesn't match a synonym a new tag gets created.  `rest-ful` != `restful`, and so the tag gets created.  The validation method(s) remove the hyphen to check against the tag list, but they don't check against synonyms.  There are also other minor issues dealing with variations of the tag that should be treated equivalently.

This should be fixed now.

Comment: But the list of synonym-master must be stored somewhere in the database and you do the look-up already when you populate the tag info. Couldn't you check the synonym list at the same time? (I assume it's a single, hierarchical, table that you do the check on? Or am I waaay off?)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards what do you mean by "populate the tag info"?

Comment: When typing a new tag in the tag box you load tag names, excerpts and synonyms. It makes it look (once again I'm completely guessing :-) as though the data's floating around somewhere without even a DB look-up.

Comment: The synonym lookups are cached, but they come from the DB.  The tags loaded when you're editing tags is just a flat list, and doesn't make use of the synonyms structure.  In any case, my point was that a new tag doesn't automatically get mapped to anything.  Someone has to do it manually.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the problem.  I'm not asking for automatic synonyms.  The problem is that `restful` existed, but then became a synonym.  Then someone created `rest-ful`.  If `restful` was a real tag and not a synonym, the system would block creation of `rest-ful` and use `restful` instead.  The behavior is inconsistent.  The system should have identified the hyphenless synonym and redirected the user.

Comment: @Charles, I think this is just v2 of the same song, and the answer is the same: `rest-ful` is _not a synonym of anything_.  Ergo, when you use it, nothing happens.

Comment: @BenCollins, that's right, but the hyphenless version of that tag, `restful` *is* a synonym.  If we de-hyphen before searching for *tags* shouldn't we also be de-hyphening when searching for synonyms?  The point is that it should have found the synonym and then redirected the user to the final tag.  Instead, the user was allowed to create it, something that can't normally be done due to the dehpyenization.

Comment: @Charles, afaik, we don't dehyphen when looking for tag suggestions.  There's this(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101543/tag-suggestion-broken-for-certain-tags-with-hyphens), which suggests that if you click a tag from the suggestion list which happens to be a synonym, it will get resolved, but that doesn't prevent someone from creating another new tag.  You can dismiss the suggestion list and create (or suggest) new tags without it.  For example: http://imgur.com/qSSSNeM

Comment: @BenCollins, could you do me a favor and try that [with a normal non-diamond account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132225/135887)?  I swear I'm not crazy and normal users *can't* create tags that differ only in hyphenation... and if that isn't the case, I'd love to know when it changed.

Comment: @Charles sure, that's a reasonable thing to ask.  I'll get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: @Charles aha! looks like you're right.  I tried it as _you_, and got this: http://i.imgur.com/V2IeO0y.png  I'll look at this more tomorrow..

Comment: @BenCollins, were you able to figure out what was going on?

Comment: @Charles I'm sorry - this slipped off my radar because I got busy with some other stuff.  I'll make time for it today.